# CQRS Implemetation

Tags: wcf, ravendb, cqrs, servicebus

I'm trying out CQRS principle. For instance:

- I want to manage the list of Supplier
- A supplier has it own address, the supplier address can be changed from the list of existing address.
- Before changing supplier's address, I need to make sure the address is not deleted.
- I'm using RavenDB database to store Suppliers, Addresses.
- UI should use WCF for synchronous calls: application <-> WCF Services <-> Service Bus <-> Database

Could you tell me how to implement this sample?

Thanks,
Phuc

Comment: Not yet, I've just read the CQRS principle and now I'm working with RavenDB for updating/getting data

Comment: So are you hoping for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: try and tell us the difficulties you meet. Then we can answer.

Comment: What I need is someone can tell me how to do this step-by-step, I mean the approach. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an event sourcing sample included with the RavenDB source, that should help you get started, see [here](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/master/Samples/Raven.Bundles.Sample.EventSourcing.ShoppingCartAggregator) and [here](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/master/Samples/Raven.Sample.EventSourcing)

Comment: I've found the solution, thanks everyone

Comment: Thanks Matt for your answer